# TypeError: Image or Canvas expected

Tags: node.js, express, canvas

This is the function i was using it with express with request params `text` in the routes for getting the image but not working

```
const { Canvas } = require('canvas-constructor')
const canvas = require('canvas')

function getStatusBanner(req, res) {
    const img = canvas.loadImage('./images/banner.jpg')
    
    let image = new Canvas(339, 94)
    .printImage(img, 0, 0, 339, 94)
    .setTextFont('12px Impact')
    .printText(req.params.text, 130, 150)
    .toBuffer();

    res.set({'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'})
    res.send(image)
}

module.exports = { getStatusBanner }
```

seems not working at all

```
TypeError: Image or Canvas expected
    at s.printImage (E:\Coding\OTHER\megumin\node_modules\canvas-constructor\dist\index.js:1:3866)
    at getStatusBanner (E:\Coding\OTHER\megumin\functions\getBanner.js:8:6)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Coding\OTHER\megumin\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\Coding\OTHER\megumin\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\Coding\OTHER\megumin\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Coding\OTHER\megumin\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\Coding\OTHER\megumin\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (E:\Coding\OTHER\megumin\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\Coding\OTHER\megumin\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at E:\Coding\OTHER\megumin\index.js:29:5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code and made some changes to make it work.

The loadImage method works asynchronously. You need to change your code to work that way.

Following the code. All that's left is to put the text parameter, but I think you can adapt to your code.

```
const { Canvas,resolveImage } = require('canvas-constructor')
const canvas = require('canvas')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000


app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const img = await createCanvas();
    res.set({'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'})
    res.send(img)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})


async function createCanvas() {
    const img = await canvas.loadImage('./images/banner.jpg');
    return new Canvas(339, 94)
        .printImage(img, 0, 0, 339, 94)
        .toBufferAsync();
}
```